# awverify CNAME not being picked up

Tags: azure, dns, cloudflare

I have setup a CNAME for my domain using the awverify.www.DOMAIN.com. I'm using CloudFlare as my DNS provider. It's been more than 48 hours and using some dig tools on the internet, I can request the awverify domain and get the right response, yet Azure management portal still says it's not a relevant domain.

Any tips/advice???

Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

Do you have that record marked with our proxy (orange cloud) in your DNS settings? That record may need to go direct until they verify (grey cloud). Try changing the cloud to off of CloudFlare in the DNS settings for that record to see if it helps.

Comment: So, it's been a while of this answer but still today it helped me with the issue I was having :)